# How to solve Package should contain a content type part [M1.13] in Word Document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create a header in word file using Apache POI but i am getting, Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]  exception.I am using the following jars

```
dom4j-1.7-2.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-2.jar
poi-3.9.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar
xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar
openxml4j.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
```

the code i am trying to run is

```
   public class TestHeader {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws XmlException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlException {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.docx");
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(input);
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(
            document);

    XWPFHeader header = headerPolicy.getDefaultHeader();
    List<XWPFTable> table = header.getTables();

    for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {
        xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(0).setText("aaa"); // document.setTable(0,
                                                        // xwpfTable);
        // header.insertTable(1, xwpfTable);
    }
    // System.out.println(header.getTables());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.docx");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();

   }

}
```

This is the exception i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:120)
at com.core.poi.TestHeader.main(TestHeader.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
... 2 more
```

Somebody please help me.

Comment: Is your document definitely docx format?

Comment: it is docx format i have office 2013 installed so it has to be

Comment: Office 2013 can create/open older document formats too.

Comment: @JamesB so where i am getting wrong,please help

Comment: How did you create this document?

Comment: using office 2013 create document and then give name of the document

Comment: `.docx` files are actually just zip files in a special structure. If you rename the file to `.zip` and unzip, can you post the list of files / folders in it?

Comment: It's a bit late now, but try with Apache POI 3.15 beta 1 or newer - you get more helpful exceptions if you pass in any of the common invalid file types now

Answer (score 1):

I get this exception too if I create a file in intellij.

```
New -> file -> with word.docx name.
```

Instead of this we should create a .docx file with openoffice/word/libreoffice and save it, then copy it into the destination folder.

Answer (score -2):

Please check your xls file name it should not be in the form like (my.file.xsl)
it should be like myfile.xsl

Comment: The OP is trying to open a Word document though, not an Excel one